# Django: Update field in Model when condition is met

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Post Model that looks like the following. When the expired timestamp is less than the now timestamp I would like the status to change from Live to Expired however the code does not seem to update when the condition is met. How can I change this so it does update

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    topic = models.CharField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES, max_length=60)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="posts_likes", blank=True, through=PostLike)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="post_dislikes", blank=True, through=PostDislike)
    # comments = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=True)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
    expired_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=expiration_time, editable=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Live")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if now >= self.expired_timestamp:
            self.status = "Expired"
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you show what `now` is?

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of 'now' you should type date.today() or datetime.datetime.now(). Lemme know if it works

```
import datetime
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if date.today() >= self.expired_timestamp:
            self.status = "Expired"
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to explicitly declare now:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if timezone.now() >= self.expired_timestamp:
        self.status = "Expired"

    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But there's a problem, this above code is executed only when the save method is called (when the instance is created or updated); so when the post is expired its status is not updated automatically (until save is called), if you want to do it automatically you have to check periodically for expired posts, maybe using cron